# Layout pushed down

Tags: theming

This is my layout http://www.gorgeoushentai.com
and this screenshot is what it looks like when logged in. You notice the background image doesn't move down if there's a toolbar. How can I make the bg image to move down with the layout? It looks perfect when logged out but broken when logged in
[image]

Comment: It sounds to me like you say it's absolutely positioned at the top for anonymous users. I may be misunderstanding, but that's not the case for me. The girl and trees in the background image follow the scroll of the rest of the page. Also, this doesn't seem like a Drupal question, but a CSS question?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the background on the body, you should create a wrapping div which holds the background image (in the page.tpl.php) Then Drupal should add the toolbar above this div and push the image down.